# Obtener IP del servidor que intenta acceder a mi API

Tags: php, api

Tengo una API básica en PHP a la cual accedo del lado del cliente por Fetch en Javascript,  y quería saber si existe alguna forma, de que  cuando el cliente acceda por Fetch entonces del lado de la API me permita obtener la IP del servidor de desde donde esta accediendo..

OJO: No estoy pidiendo la IP de la PC del cliente sino del servidor... por ejemplo si acceden desde un sitio web como www.ejemplo.com, la idea es capturar la IP del servidor de www.ejemplo.com

Comment: No estoy pidiendo IP del cliente estoy pidiendo IP del servidor es muy diferente

Comment: Por favor quita el duplicado estoy pidiendo es IP del servidor no del cliente

Comment: No logro entender. O sea, en `www.tuweb.com` tienes una página desde la cual, vía Javascript, accedes a otra dirección `www.otraweb.com` y ¿quieres obtener la IP del servidor  de `www.otraweb.com`? ¿Te entendí bien? Luego, ¿dónde querrías obtener la IP del servidor, en `www.tuweb.com` o en `www.otraweb,com`? No sé, es algo confuso el planteamiento. Si conoces de antemano la dirección puedes hacer uso de [`gethostbyname`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.gethostbyname.php) para obtener la IP de esa dirección.

Comment: Basicamente no, no puedes. Lo que puedes obtener es la ip publica del cliente, pero no del servidor que el cliente esta visitando. Para consegirlo podrías generar token temporales y que tenga que ser el servidor-cliente el que haga la peticion para obtener el token y valides para entregar un token válido o obligar a que te envie una url en las peticiones, que podría ser o no la sel servidor.